# ASP.NET 2.0 C# Admin page can decide which products are to be displayed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0

My website that sells products one page is called dvd.aspx which, using a sproc, displays all the dvds in my database with the "type=dvd". I have some admin pages in an admin folder where i can add new product, edit existing products but i need to let the admin decide which items to display, would anyone have any advice on how to go about this, do i need to create a page in admin folder for this or maybe edit code behind dvd.aspx page?
Any kind of advice is welcome,
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new column in you table called somehing like `"ToShow"` and make it a bit type, edit your `dvd.aspx` to show items with `type=dvd` and `ToShow=true`.

Create admin page, add GridView with the option to change ToShow property. That way admin can select items to show.

Just a friendly advice,move to .net 4.0 and you can use some [Object-relational mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) like Linq to Sql,NHibernate or Entity Framework, it would make your life a lot easier!

Comment: Thank you for the idea, i have set up a new "toshow" column and admin can edit from his page.  Added to sproc to now display if toshow=true.
i will advance to 4.0 just for this 'project' i need to complete in 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

A flag on the product which indicates if it should be displayed. The admin can then adjust the flag to determine if it should be selected by your sproc.